# clustering of singular values

Tags: matlab, regression

let us consider following graph of singular values

[image]

i want to make  some kind of  clustering of these data,namely to  seperate  main components from non main components,let say signal components from noise components,i would like to do like this(any software matlab,etc is great,better matlab)let us start like this  ,first do linear regression  with first point,then do regression analysis with first two point and so on,point is that  one want to  create two group,in first group   coefficients of  regression lines should be  close to each other, also in another group  regression coefficients should be close to each other,but regression  coefficients  in one group must be highly different then coefficients in another group,that means that we should find such point which separate this groups optimally,  in other word i should stop regression analysis at some point which  well separate  two group,and another regression will start after this stop point till other rest points,please help me how to do it programaticaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think cumulative measures are often used for this sort of thing. For instance, for a given SNR,

$$
10^{\mathrm{SNR}/10}={ S \over N},
$$

where $S$ is the signal power and $N$ is the noise power, we know that the ratio of the signal power to the total power is

$$
{ S \over {S+N}} = { S \over {S \left( 1 + 1/10^{\mathrm{SNR}/10} \right) } }
= { 10^{\mathrm{SNR}/10} \over 10^{\mathrm{SNR}/10} + 1 }.
$$

Thus, you would accumulate the power in the largest singular values until their sum approached or exceeded the above ratio. The remaining singular vlaues will then correspond to the noise components.

Comment: thanks for help ,but point is that we dont know  signal and noise  powers in reality

Comment: also what should  be more that this limit?power of singular values?do you mean sum of singular values?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Power is usually $\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert^2$, while energy is $\sum \vert x_i \vert$. The sum I am referring to would be found by starting with the largest singular value and then adding the second largest, then the third largest, and so on.

Comment: thanks but as i mentioned problem is that i dont know SNR

Comment: If you don't have an estimate of the SNR, then, yeah, the above won;t do you much good. Sorry.

Comment: no no thanks for help

Comment: i did not this formula,what i need is partially regression

Comment: There's got to be a better way to estimate the SNR than looking for a change in the slope of the running sum though. It sounds like your problem is one of SNR estimation.

Comment: i will not accept this answer  despite  that thanks for help,because  maybe someone will help me with statistically